# MongoDB Core: dumped

Tags: database, mongodb, ubuntu

I am trying to install mongoDB on my Ubuntu. i have followed the required steps as stipulated on the MongoDB website but whene i input the commands that checks status of my mongoDB, i keep getting this result: Active: failed (Result: core-dump)

I have tried deleting the packages and libs but it is still not working.
i am using ubuntu 86_64 and i don't know what else is missing.
I am expecting to see the MongoDB running, but it isn't.[This is a screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BliMe.png).

In my mongoDB compass, when i want to connect to a database, this error message keeps popping up.[The error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxvEO.png)

Comment: Try restarting the service with `systemctl restart mongod`

Comment: I have tried restarting the server but nothing still

Comment: If you have MongoDB compass, try checking there, if you're able to connect to the database.